# Add empty view to listview

Tags: android, listview, layout

No, it's not a duplicate.

I have a `ListView` (not the `View` in a layout xml file, the `View` as class) and want to display a view for the empty state. 
The `addView` method isn't available, simple replacing the `ListView` doesn't work, because the parent is a `ViewPager`.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: There is no `EmptyView` in the Android SDK. A `ListActivity` or a `ListFragment` has the concept of an "empty view" that is shown when the list is empty, but that is a feature of those classes, not of `ListView`.

Comment: Yeah, there is no `EmptyView`. I know, sorry. The actual method for setting the view for the empty state is located in the `AdapterView` class. Anyway, there is no official way to achieve my plan? So I have to work around, nothing new.

Comment: "The actual method for setting the view for the empty state is located in the AdapterView class" -- I had never realized that. I have only ever seen the "empty view" construct with `ListFragment` and `ListActivity` and had assumed it was implemented there. My apologies. But then I am confused. Why not just call `setEmptyView()`?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java The method is in line 729.
I set my `adapter` to null, create a simple `TextView` and call setEmptyView. The problem is, the view need to be added to the `ListView` or the parent layout. My parent is a `ViewPager` and I can't figure out how to create a view on only one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My parent is a ViewPager and I can't figure out how to create a view on only one page

Your pages for your `ViewPager` are being created by some form of `PagerAdapter`. Presumably, from the way you are describing things, you rolled your own `PagerAdapter`, rather than using one of the built-in fragment-based ones. And, presumably, that `PagerAdapter` is returning a `ListView` for one or more of the pages, for which you want an "empty view".

Simply put: you are going to have to change that `PagerAdapter`. Instead of returning a `ListView`, return something like a `FrameLayout` containing your `ListView` and your "empty view". Whether you create those objects in Java or via inflating a layout resource is up to you. Along the way, call `setEmptyView()` on the `ListView` to tie the `ListView` and the "empty view" together.

Comment: So easy, that I can't figure it out. Thanks a lot. Maybe it's just to late.